# Question about ISupportErrorInfo::InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo() implementation

Tags: c++, com, atl

I am a babysitter now overlooking a huge old-time (started in last century) code base for Windows, using C++ and C#, largely using COM as a glue.

I noticed that `ISupportErrorInfo::InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo()` implementations (around 400 of them, wow) are just naive, exactly as [here](http://computer-programming-forum.com/77-vc-atl/b07f73ea0d2723c3.htm):

```cpp
STDMETHOD(InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo)(REFIID riid)
{
    static const IID* arr[] =
    {
        &IID_IStore,
    };
    
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
        if (InlineIsEqualGUID(*arr[i], riid))
            return S_OK;
    }
    
    return S_FALSE;
}
```

It looks to me that, once upon a time, someone (MVP, evangelist) has written a book about COM and then everybody later just copied these lines without thinking.

First of all, why do I need an array if I only have one item in it?  Without an array, I don't need a for-loop.

To me, it looks like one line will be fine, eg.

```cpp
return MyCoolHelper::InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo(riid, IID_IStore);
```

Maybe you have seen a decent implementation of it that supports 1 or more IID-s?

Comment: Nobody wrote or copied that code, it was auto-generated by the [ATL wizard](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2980/Small-ATL-Tricks-Part-One).  Modifying it is not terribly sensible.

Comment: Yeah... Computers can write programs :)

Comment: It is not uncommon for COM objects to implement multiple interfaces, even tear-off interfaces, aggregate interfaces, etc, each interface needing to support `ISupportErrorInfo` using its own IID.  I've written COM objects like that before (and NOT by using VS or ATL wizards, either).

Comment: Yes, there may be multiple interfaces that the component can support error info. But I see in 90% of cases it's 1.

Comment: Not an answer, but (assuming it’s ATL): I would advise you that part of maintaining an ATL project is to learn what parts of the source code are your responsibility, and which parts are maintained by Visual Studio and you should ignore completely. I’m not saying it’s easy. Start with a minimalistic approach: for an established code base you can often limit yourself to only modifying method implementations and below. Play with creating a few toy projects to see what gets maintained for you. Master this and it will all be easier for you as you will have a lot less surface area to worry about.